# Ionic how to transition and reload a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to build an application, but every since ios 9 update my code is broken.

this is my code when the user click logOut it launches a function that change state and then refresh the page.

```
$scope.logOut = function () {
  $localStorage.$reset();
  $state.go('login');
  $window.location.reload();
};
```

But now I noticed that my $state.go is a async and the $window.location.reload() launches before the transitions finishes. there any way that I can wait for my transition to finish before the page reload ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the $state.go and reload call and replace with

```
$window.location.href = "/login";
```

Or whatever your login path is.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code, just remove the `$window.location.reload();`

```
$scope.logOut = function () {
    $localStorage.$reset();
    $state.go('login');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine to refresh states.

```
$window.location.href = $state.href('someState');
// reload the page
$window.location.reload();
```